# look up for master data in R

Tags: r, compare, lookup

i have a a problem with the following topic.

After using Excel, the workload of doing this is to high. Now i want to do it with R in a automatic way.

I have different Models of washing machines:

For Every Model, i have a data.frame with all required Components. FOR 1 MODEL AS EXAMPLE

```
Component = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J")
Number = c(1,1,1,2,4,1,1,1,2,3)
Model.A= data.frame(Component,Quantity)
```

As second Information, i have a data.frame with all Components, which are used by all Models and in addition the actual Stock of these Components.

```
Component = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z")
Stock = c(100,102,103,105,1800,500,600,400,50,80,700,900,600,520,35,65,78,95,92,50,36,34,96,74,5,76)

Comp.Stock = data.frame(Component,Stock)
```

The third and last Inforamtion is about the weekly production plan. I have 4 weekly production plans = Plan for 1 months. I got a data.frame with the Models of washing machines, which will be produced in the next 4 weeks and also the quantitiy of them.

```
pr.Models= c("MODEL.A","MODEL.B","MODEL.C","MODEL.D")
Quantity= c(15000,1000,18000,16000,5000)

Production= data.frame(pr.Models,Quantity)
```

My Problem is now, to combine these informations together, that i can compare the models which get produced ( last information) with the components. First with the used components for every Model on its own and in addition with the data.frame which has the information of all components and the stock.

The Aim is to get information and a warning, if the Component stock is not big enough for producing the models from the production plan.

Hind: ( Many same Components gets used by different Models)

Hopefully you understand what i mean and can help me by this problem.

Thank you =)

EDIT:

I can not follow all your steps:

Maybe this idea is also good, but i nead a hind how to do it:

Maybe it is possible to merge every produced Model (Production) with the Used Components. (considered with the Quantity for Producing and the Number need per Washing machine).

My prefered output is, to gert automattically dataframes for every produced model with the needed Components.

In the next step it should be able to merge these datas with Comp.Stock to see which Component are needed how often and compare this with the stock.

Have you any ideas on this way?

Maybe i am to stupid for the presented way... I really need an automatic way because there are more then 4k different components and more then 180 different models of washing machines.

Thank you

the Comp.Stock additionally with all used Models and their quanitity ( Production)

Comment: Hello, Just a quick aside, when you are creating `data.frame`s using objects that you have already created, do not use quotes, as this `Model.A= data.frame("Component","Quantity")`  will simply give you a data.frame of two strings, the words `"Component"` and `"Quantity"`.    Instead use  `Model.A= data.frame(Component, Quantity)`

Comment: also, have a look at `?merge`

Comment: ok of course you are right with the data.frame information i correct it

Comment: i looked at merge, but i do not know how to do : (

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have the model name as a column in the first data.frame (to match `Production`)

```
Model.A$pr.Models <- 'MODEL.A'
```

Then you can merge.  Note that there are two "Quantity" columns, and you don't want to merge by those:

```
merged <- merge(merge(Model.A, Comp.Stock),Production, by='pr.Models')
```

`Extra` is how many you will have on-hand after production:

```
transform(transform(merged, Needed = Quantity.x * Quantity.y), Extra = Stock - Needed)
##    pr.Models Component Quantity.x Stock Quantity.y Needed  Extra
## 1    MODEL.A         A          1   100      15000  15000 -14900
## 2    MODEL.A         B          1   102      15000  15000 -14898
## 3    MODEL.A         C          1   103      15000  15000 -14897
## 4    MODEL.A         D          2   105      15000  30000 -29895
## 5    MODEL.A         E          4  1800      15000  60000 -58200
## 6    MODEL.A         F          1   500      15000  15000 -14500
## 7    MODEL.A         G          1   600      15000  15000 -14400
## 8    MODEL.A         H          1   400      15000  15000 -14600
## 9    MODEL.A         I          2    50      15000  30000 -29950
## 10   MODEL.A         J          3    80      15000  45000 -44920
```

If `Extra` is negative, you'll need more parts.  You're seriously deficient.

```
transform(transform(merged, Needed = Quantity.x * Quantity.y), Extra = Stock - Needed)$Extra < 0
##  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Not enough of any part.

As a function:

```
Not.Enough.Parts <- function(Model, Comp.Stock, Production) {
  Model$pr.Models <- toupper(substitute(Model))
  merged <- merge(merge(Model, Comp.Stock),Production, by='pr.Models')
  extra <- transform(transform(merged, Needed = Quantity.x * Quantity.y), Extra = Stock - Needed)
  retval <- extra$Extra < 0
  names(retval) <- extra$Component
  return(retval)
}

Not.Enough.Parts(Model.A, Comp.Stock, Production)
##    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J 
## TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: can i automize your first step? because there are over 20 different models produced in a month and i want to give this code to somebody who has no idea of r. So it should be easy as possible for him. That i need the model name as a colum is clear you are right.. Maybe i can change the readed Exelfile to have this information out of Excel?..... I mean without looking at the Productionplan just for every Model on its own....

Comment: That's there to extract the `MODEL.A` row from `Production`.  In real use, you would (or rather, should) have multiple models in the first data frame (or rbind multiple together after adding the model name).  But yes, it can be automated:  `Model.A$pr.Models <- toupper(substitute(Model.A))` (this can be used in a function, in which `Model.A` is passed as a parameter).

Comment: Hello, i edit my first post because i can not follow your presented, or better to say i can not get the needed benefit...  if you need more precise data, please tell me

Comment: @Daniel I'll try to look at this tomorrow.  Several things do come to mind though.  First, you should not mark an answer as accepted if it does not solve the problem.  Second, it would be good to give examples of multiple Models, and state how you want to combine the results of them.  My answer works for one, but clearly you have several.